# Rows.count incorrect

Tags: vba, excel

I have: `N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` 
and it returns 1 all the time, when I have a dataset which contains 200k+ rows.

Very odd, as it is only with this workbook, as with another workbook this line works.

Questions:

Any suggestions as to why this occurs?
Any possible work around? My current work around is:

```
Sub Macro2()

    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    n = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `N = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: you are likely referencing the wrong parent worksheet.

Comment: Is the code in the same workbook as the data?

Comment: @0m3r: I receive a compile error: 'Invalid or unqualified reference'

Comment: I guess, the column 'B' does not contain any data in this specific worksheet and hence the silution. Try with a different column.

Comment: stop working with select/activesheet, and start referencing sheets, workbooks !

Answer (score 4):

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Example()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Dim LAST_ROW As Long
            LAST_ROW = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Debug.Print LAST_ROW ' Print on Immediate Window
    End With
End Sub
```

*Multiple ways finding last row*

```
Private Sub Example2()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    Dim LAST_ROW As Long

    'Using Find
      LAST_ROW = Sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                                     searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    'Using SpecialCells
      LAST_ROW = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    'Ctrl + Shift + End
      LAST_ROW = Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'UsedRange
      LAST_ROW = Sht.UsedRange.Rows(Sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    'Using Named Range
      LAST_ROW = Sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

    'Ctrl + Shift + Down
      LAST_ROW = Sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want the code to run in active (selected) sheet. Example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub LastrowExample()
    'declare variable lastrow as Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    'get lastrow:
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 
    'or lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End sub
```

should work.
However I always prefer to specify at least the sheet first, to make sure my code run from anywhere, like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub LastrowExample2()
    'declare variable lastrow as Long
    Dim lastrow as Long
    'declare sheet
     Dim ws As Worksheet
    'get sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mysheetname") 

    'get lastrow:
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 
    'or 
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End sub
```