# Processs cells with values only in a hardcoded range

Tags: vba, excel

I have code to draft emails to all the recipient in column 'G'.

```
    Sub Send_Bulk_Mail()

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

  For Each cell In ws.Range("G2:G100")

    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

        With objMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "This is the test subject"
            .Body = "This is the test email body"
            .Send
        End With

        Set objMail = Nothing
    Next cell

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

When there are fewer rows than 100 in column G, there is an error after drafting all the emails.

How can I stop automatically after the last email?

Here is the link to sample [Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rH3kWgAgIMnS9SkZILUk4aNwz2BGhVVH/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Or simply use [Range.End Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-end-property-excel)*

```
Dim rCell As Range
For Each rCell In Ws.Range("G2", Ws.Range("G100").End(xlUp))
     'code here 
Next rCell
```

---

*Full Example*

```
Option Explicit
Sub Send_Bulk_Mail()
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In Ws.Range("G2", Ws.Range("G100").End(xlUp))
        Debug.Print rCell.Address
        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

        With objMail
            .To = rCell.Value
            .Subject = "This is the test subject"
            .Body = "This is the test email body"
            .Send
        End With

    Next rCell

    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set Ws = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

*See more Examples here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48497589/4539709*

Answer (score 1):

Put a check on `Cell` to see if it's nothing before trying to use it.

```
If Not cell Is Nothing Then
  If cell.Value <> "" Then
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    With objMail
        .To = cell.Value
        .Subject = "This is the test subject"
        .Body = "This is the test email body"
        .Send
    End With
  End If
End IF
```

Comment: Sound to me like you didnt copy/paste the right things. Is your `For` line still in there? or did you replace it?

Comment: Yes, that line is still there. Without that line how the code will know where the email addresses are? Can you show me the complete code?